# multivariate cox regression - combining genotypes for each SNP

Tags: survival, cox-model, multivariate-regression, gwas

For 53 SNP I have coded genotypes as 0 for aa, 1 for ab, and 2 for bb for 29 samples and I have outcome and time to outcome. Here outcome is called "BCR" below.

I am using the [survival package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) to run a cox regression analysis on 7/53 SNPs:

```
require(survival)
load("sam_christos.Rdata")

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, BCR) ~ chr5_91073986_T_A + chr8_128106880_A_C + 
chr11_2233574_A_G + chr11_68978580_G_A + chr13_28895069_A_G + 
chr17_36074979_G_A + chr17_69108753_G_T, data =  sam)
```

sam_christos.Rdata can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AqNBH4JHmEM2xtf7Kte8MkyKRK7KfBPP/view?usp=sharing)

But I can not seem to combine all the genotypes for each SNP into one score as res.cox looks like this

> res.cox
>   Call:
>   coxph(formula = Surv(time, BCR) ~ chr5_91073986_T_A + chr8_128106880_A_C + 
>       chr11_2233574_A_G + chr11_68978580_G_A + chr13_28895069_A_G + 
>       chr17_36074979_G_A + chr17_69108753_G_T, data = sam)

```
                     coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z    p
chr5_91073986_T_A1  -1.19e+00  3.05e-01  1.36e+00 -0.87 0.38
chr5_91073986_T_A2   5.84e-01  1.79e+00  2.33e+00  0.25 0.80
chr8_128106880_A_C2  1.67e+01  1.76e+07  3.44e+03  0.00 1.00
chr11_2233574_A_G1  -2.14e+00  1.18e-01  2.96e+00 -0.72 0.47
chr11_2233574_A_G2  -4.94e-01  6.10e-01  3.11e+00 -0.16 0.87
chr11_68978580_G_A2  1.92e+01  2.08e+08  3.44e+03  0.01 1.00
chr13_28895069_A_G1  2.19e+01  3.41e+09  1.75e+05  0.00 1.00
chr13_28895069_A_G2  2.66e+01  3.52e+11  1.75e+05  0.00 1.00
chr17_36074979_G_A2  7.29e-01  2.07e+00  1.48e+00  0.49 0.62
chr17_69108753_G_T1  2.76e+00  1.58e+01  3.20e+00  0.86 0.39
chr17_69108753_G_T2  1.50e+00  4.49e+00  1.50e+00  1.00 0.32

Likelihood ratio test=21.6  on 11 df, p=0.0281
```

n= 29, number of events= 8

Is there a way to combine the score for each SNP so that chr5_91073986_T_A1 and chr5_91073986_T_A2 (code 1 - ab and 2 - bb) for the SNP at chr5:91073986-91073986 can be scored together?

Comment: You can try an interaction term (multiplying them instead of adding, e.g. chr5_91073986_T_A1*chr5_91073986_T_A2). Interpreting interactions is always tricky, though.